# FIX - Determining message length?

Tags: fix-protocol

In FIX what determines a message length? Because I have read if a message exceeds its length it will be sent in fragments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splitting up large messages is not an implicit part of the FIX protocol.

Some counterparties may choose to split up data into multiple messages instead of sending giant messages, but they don't have to.  In my experience, I've seen counterparties send ridiculously large messages.

If a message is split up, it's because the sending party chose to implement their system that way.

Comment: Thank you. Its just I was reading FIX Best practices and they didn't mention what determines message length.

Comment: Do you mean the BodyLength field (tag 9)?  That's different.  That's a very specific calculation, but it's defined in the spec.

Comment: Well I assumed you meant by giant messages you were referring to  BodyLength field.

Comment: Well, they are related.  If the BodyLength field is not accurate, the receiver will probably reject the message.  But there is no maximum size to a message.